# Stop Zend Form element errors from escaping HTML

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have a Zend text Element that contains HTML in the label. I can stop Zend from escaping the HTML in there by adding the `->setOption('escape', false);` option. This works as expected.

However, when there is an error, the error shows the label HTML escaped as the title of the error message. I get something that looks like this:

```
<strong>First</strong> name
Please enter your first name
```

I'm thinking of a couple of ways I can get around this, but not sure if either are possible. Can I change the format of the error so it doesn't use the input label directly? Or is there a way to stop Zend from escaping the HTML in the errors?

**Edit:** I'm not showing each input error beside the input. Instead, I'm grouping all the errors and displaying them at once. Each element has the error decorator removed:

```
$firstName->removeDecorator('Errors');
```

And then I'm displaying them as a group by adding the `FormErrors` decorator:

```
$myForm->setDecorators(array('FormErrors', ....));
```

I think this is what causes the label of the input to show as part of the errors list.

Comment: What is generating the error message? At least in ZF1, the default error message decorator doesn't include the label as a title for the error.

Comment: @Divey Thanks Divey, I've updated my question to what I should've written in the first place. I'm grouping the errors using the `FormErrors` form decorator, so I think this is what shows the labels as titles?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `FormErrors` decorator, then you have two options how to stop escaping the labels:

First option: 
Specify another Zend_View escape callback using `Zend_View::setEscape` method
Second option:
Create custom `FormErrors` decorator and override `renderLabel` method.

Example:

```
class My_Form_Decorator_FormErrors extends Zend_Form_Decorator_FormErrors
{
    public function renderLabel(Zend_Form_Element $element, Zend_View_Interface $view)
    {
        return $this->getMarkupElementLabelStart()
             . $element->getLabel()
             . $this->getMarkupElementLabelEnd();
    }    
}

class Forms_Example extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        /* ... */
        $this->addPrefixPath('My_Form_Decorator', 'My/Form/Decorator', 'decorator');
        /* ... */   
    }
}
```